# Why do search APIs return different results from the main search engine?

Tags: ruby, api, search, bing-api

I've been playing around with the Google and Bing search APIs, and I've noticed that even when both are configured to search the entire web, the APIs return different results from conducting searches on the actual search engines.

I've also noticed that for very long queries, the APIs tend to return very few results, and sometimes no results when a normal search on their website would return many results.

Why is this?

Comment: How are you using their API? Can you post a code example? Also worth noting that the computer, browser, etc are all taken into aspect when searching, so that can make a difference.

Comment: I don't see how me posting a code example would help. It's just from checking out the JSON returned from a url endpoint.

Comment: @Justin, someone else could learn something from your question. The point is not just to let you take information from others. But also to give valuable information to others. The more value you give away, the more value you get back.

Comment: @Alexey I agree 100% with what you're saying. My point is that me adding more information to the question would not help anyone learn anything new nor help people answer the question more effectively.

Comment: @Justin, maybe we just have different perspectives. I was looking through the new questions with tag 'ruby' and just come across this one. I thought "wow, Ruby api for search engines. I wonder what is it." I expected to see at least a name of a gem or code sample. I think in this case it's better to remove 'ruby' tag.

Comment: oh i just added a ruby tag because that's what i use to parse the JSON

Answer (score 1):

Search Engines tend to weight the results based on your own usage patterns online.  Let's say you search for "Fluffy kitten", and you regularly spend time browsing around bar/restaurant directory sites, you might get that new hipster bar "Fluffy Kitten" at the top of your search results, while the person who spend more time reading pet fanatic sites might get the cute and cuddly search results.

This often catches people out who think their cool new site is number one in Google, when in fact, nobody else has the result at #1 and Google is just favouring it for them based on their online activity.

The APIs don't have the same knowledge about the user, so your results will vary.

There may be other reasons, but this usage-tracking stuff is very true.